# How does dmesg differentiate between different log levels?

Tags: linux, dmesg

How does dmesg differentiate between different log levels?

I can execute `dmesg -l err` to see all the error logs but when I look at the data with just `dmesg` or just `cat` the `/var/log/dmesg` file, there is no tag/string/identifier in the log text that can differentiate `err` from `warn`.

How does dmesg store this differentiation of log levels? How does it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The dmesg(1) command does not read the `/var/log/dmesg` file, rather, it reads [/dev/kmsg](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg) which contains the necessary syslog facility and priority information.